# Issue in chrome when using cursormanager(Its Displaying both custom cursor and normal mouse pointer)

Tags: flex3, flashplayer-9

I am using cursor manager to set the hand cursor for the overlay.

its works fine in mozilla firefox and IE8, but in chrome its shows the hand cursor and also the normal mouse pointer, here is my code

```
import mx.managers.CursorManager;
import mx.managers.CursorManagerPriority;
[Embed(source="/assets/images/cursor_hand.gif")]
    public var handCursor:Class;

renderer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(event:MouseEvent):void{
                        CursorManager.setCursor(handCursor,CursorManagerPriority.HIGH, 3, 2);
                    });
                    renderer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, function(event:MouseEvent):void{
                        CursorManager.removeAllCursors();
                    });
```

Am I missed anything here?
I am using flex builder 3 and Flash player 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-custom-cursor-tutorial) link in Chrome and check whether the you are seeing custom cursor alone. If no, try to update your Flash Player version.I have version I have version 10,0,45,2 and I am seeing only the custom cursor in chrome.